# $(...).Jcrop is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I have read articles on

> '$(...)Jcrop is not a function'.

I have ensured that I have not included the Jcrop links twice.

JCrop seems to be giving me trouble

Can someone please help.

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.Jcrop.min.css" />

    <div class="profile-pic">
        <label>Profile Pic</label>
        <input type="file" name="profile_pic" id="profile-pic-input">
        <img src="images/volunteer.jpg" id="profile-pic">
    </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#profile-pic-input').change(function(){
        readURLProfile(this);
    });

    $('#profile-pic-input').change(function(){
        $('#profile-pic').Jcrop();
    });

    function readURLProfile(input) {
        if(input.files&&input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload=function(e) {
                $('#profile-pic').attr('src',e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: have you checked that the jcrop file is actually loading correctly into your page (e.g. maybe you gave an incorrect URL for it)?

Comment: I ask because, if you include a valid link to the jCrop files, then your code doesn't seem to throw any errors. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/avx3wdfm/

Comment: Thanks for the revert. I have checked again. The link seems correct. Only after i auto-populate the image, i get the error '$(...).Jcrop is not a function'

Comment: "seems correct"...or **is** correct? Have you actually checked, via your browser's developer tools, whether it is loading correctly or not? open the Developer Tools (press F12 in most browsers)...go to the "Network" section....now refresh your page (press F5 in most browsers)...watch the network tool...you'll see a line for "js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"...does it return a 200 OK response, or not? If it isn't loading, then jQuery will not know about the Jcrop function, which would result in the error you're seeing.

Comment: Yes. Did as you advised. It shows 200 under status.

Comment: In that case it should work as per my demo. Unless perhaps you have some incompatibility between your version of jQuery and your version of jCrop. I can't think what else could be happening.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Let me see if there is another way out.

Comment: You can remode the `FileReader` and just do `$('#profile-pic').attr('src',URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]));`

Answer (score 3):

The issue was I had another instance of jquery script running at the footer which was throwing the error. Sorry for the confusion.